# Parse AJAX form submition

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, coldfusion-9

I have a jQuery Mobile app that has several dynamic forms. What I am trying to do is parse the form submissions and get the value of the form field. When the data is received from the processing script, it looks as follows.

```
str:app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746_ser=a&app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746_app=A1234Washer%2C+ABC&app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746_chk=&app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814747_ser=a&app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814747_app=A1234Dryer%2C+ABC&app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814747_chk=
```

What I need to do from there is get the values of each of these an put them in a 2 dimensional array.

I need to further explain the formfields in order for you to seem my problem. I will break down the formfield.

- This formfield is an appliance serial number:
  app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746_ser=a
- The applianceType is: EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746
- EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746 = Washer
- Serial Number = a

---

- This formfield is the Brand and Name of Appliance:
  app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746_app=A1234Washer%2C+ABC
- The appliance type is: EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746
- Washer Brand and Name: A1234Washer, ABC

---

- This formfield is an active checkbox:
  app_EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746_chk=
- The applianceType is: EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746

---

So what I am trying to do with this information is loop over this data and insert the form values along with the appropriate applianceType. First I query the active appliance types.

```
<cfquery name="qApplianceTypes">
    SELECT *
    FROM ApplianceTypes
    WHERE Active = <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit">
</cfquery>
```

Then I loop over the results and match up the formfields applianceTypes in order to get the values and apply it to the array.

```
    <cfset applianceTypeArray = ArrayNew(2)>

    <cfset count = 1>

<cfloop query="qqApplianceTypes">
    <!--- [1] appliance id ---->
    <cfset applianceTypeArray[count][1]     =   qApplianceType.ApplianceTypeID>
        <!--- loop over formfields to find relative id --->
        <cfloop index="i" list="#Form.str#" delimiters=",">
            <cfif right(i, 4) IS "_IDd" and qApplianceType.ApplianceTypeID is "#GetToken(ListFirst(i,' '),2,'_')#" >
                <!--- [4] appliance ---->
                <cfset applianceTypeArray[count][2]     =   #FORM[i]#>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
        <!--- loop over formfields to find relative serialnumbers --->
        <cfloop index="i" list="#Form.str#" delimiters=",">
            <cfif right(i, 4) IS "_ser" and qApplianceType.ApplianceTypeID is "#GetToken(ListFirst(i,' '),2,'_')#" >
                <!--- [3] serial number ---->
                <cfset applianceTypeArray[count][3]     =   #FORM[i]#>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
        <!--- loop over formfields to find relative appliance --->
        <cfloop index="i" list="#Form.str#" delimiters=",">
            <cfif right(i, 4) IS "_app" and qApplianceType.ApplianceTypeID is "#GetToken(ListFirst(i,' '),2,'_')#" >
                <!--- [4] appliance ---->
                <cfset applianceTypeArray[count][4]     =   #FORM[i]#>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    <cfset applianceTypeArray[count][5]     =   qApplianceType.ApplianceTypeID>

        <!--- loop over formfields to find relative active or innactive --->
        <cfloop index="i" list="#Form.str#" delimiters=",">
            <cfif right(i, 4) IS "_chk" and qApplianceType.ApplianceTypeID is "#GetToken(ListFirst(i,' '),2,'_')#" >
                <!--- [2] active ---->
                <cfset applianceTypeArray[count][6]     =   #FORM[i]#>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    <cfset qloopcount2 = #count#>
    <cfset count = count+1>
</cfloop>
```

Once I get the applianceTypeArray populated, I simply loop over the array to populate the database.

The problem is that I am not getting the values. It works is a form post but I have to use a get. When I dump the array, I get the following data.

```
0: "EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746"
1: null
2: null
3: null
4: "EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814746"

0: "EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814747"
1: null
2: null
3: null
4: "EAD17776-155D-D714-FB34E569AA814747"
```

First issue is that the elements start with 0 instead of 1 and I am not getting a elements 6. Second is that elements 0 - 4 are not the values but rather the appliance type ids.
Any suggestions?